# Add an Attachment to BMC Remedy Incident using Python/Rest API

Tags: python, rest, remedy

I am trying to add an attachment to the existing incident using BMC rest-api with python 3.6, For some reason it did not work for me, however I was able to add an attachment using Postman without any issues,  but not thru this python code.  Sometime I get Http 500 error and sometime Http 400 bad requests. Any one is aware what am I doing wrong? much appreciated.
I have been stuck at this for few weeks now and no clue to move forward, unable to find any documentation from BMC, any direction much appreciated

Using python 3.6

```
import requests

url = "https://restapi/api/arsys/v1/entry/HPD:WorkLog"

payload = {
"entry": {
    "values": {
        "Incident Number": "INC000020972030",
        "z1D Action": "CREATE",
        "Work Log Type": "General Information",
        "View Access": "Internal",
        "Secure Work Log": "No",
        "Detailed Description": "Add your description",
        "z2AF Work Log01": "sample.txt"
    }
}}

files=[('attach-z2AF Work Log01'('sample.txt',open('/Users/Downloads/sample.txt','rb'),'text/plain'))]

headers = {
'Authorization': 'AR-JWT authentication token here',
'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload,files=files,verify=False)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: No, still facing the same issue, researching it.

Comment: Postman doesn't send the attachment at all, if you chek the console, it sends undefined elements, check the code provided on my answer

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203863/php-remedy-api-call-to-create-an-entry-with-attachment-not-working-with-postman/75227562?noredirect=1#comment132748985_75227562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long struggle I was able to add an attachment to the remedy incident, Thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946962/8741275

Incase if any one looking for the answer here is the working version:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://restapi.onbmc.com/api/arsys/v1/entry/HPD:WorkLog"

payload = {
         'values': { 
         'Incident Number': 'INC000020972030',
         'z1DAction':'CREATE',
         'Work Log Type': 'General Information', 
         'View Access':'Internal', 
         'Secure Work Log': 'No', 
         'Detailed Description': 'Add your description', 
         'z2AF Work Log01': 'sample.txt' 
         }}
 
files = {
          'entry': ('entry', json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),
          'attach-z2AF Work Log01':('sample.txt',open('/Users/Downloads/sample.txt', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
 }
 
 headers = {'Authorization' : 'AR-JWT authentication token here'}
 
 res = requests.post(url, files=files,headers=headers,verify=False)
 print(res.status_code)
```